# Error in Rendering android layout. unknown exception error for width

Tags: android

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:877)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
        at uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar.onDraw_Original(ProgressBar.java:62)
        at uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar.onDraw(ProgressBar.java)
```

> **Layout_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:weightSum="1">
    <!-- android:background="@drawable/orangeback"-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main.weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="52sp"
        tools:text="Icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main.temperature"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.34"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        tools:text="20" />

    <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressCircle
          android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
          android:layout_width="166dp"
          android:layout_height="148dp"
          android:layout_margin="30dp"
          android:textSize="80sp"
          android:textColor="#BBD452"
          app:progressColor="#BBD452"
          app:incompleteProgressColor="#D4D4D4"
          app:strokeWidth="15dp"

          />

   <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
          android:layout_margin="20dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.10"
          />

      <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/progress_bar2"
          android:layout_margin="20dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.11"
          />

      <GridLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="410dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          >


          <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressCircle
          android:id="@+id/progress_circle2"
              android:layout_width="105dp"
              android:layout_height="95dp"
              android:textSize="36sp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
              app:progressColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
              app:incompleteProgressColor="#D4D4D4"
              app:strokeWidth="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
              android:layout_row="0"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:layout_marginLeft="45dp" />

          <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressCircle
              android:id="@+id/progress_circle3"
              android:layout_width="105dp"
              android:layout_height="95dp"
              android:textSize="36sp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
              app:progressColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
              app:incompleteProgressColor="#D4D4D4"
              app:strokeWidth="10dp"
              android:layout_row="0"
              android:layout_column="2"
              android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
              android:elevation="0dp"
              android:layout_margin="-2dp" />

          <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressCircle
          android:id="@+id/progress_circle4"
              android:layout_width="105dp"
              android:layout_height="95dp"
              android:textSize="36sp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
          app:progressColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
          app:incompleteProgressColor="#D4D4D4"
          app:strokeWidth="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
              android:layout_margin="5dp"
              android:layout_row="0"
              android:layout_column="1"
              />


      </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am getting strange Errors in layout due to Illegal Argument exception. I really do not understand what is going wrong. Please guide. My width and height are always `>0` when I check using `Logcat`. This error does not block compiling, I can build code successfully. But it does not allow me to see the Design Format of my `Layout_cell.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your `uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar` `layout_width` and `layout_height` to some constant dimension.

For example:

```
<uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.10"/>
```

Comment: Ia km still getting the same error after Setting constant layout_width and height. I observed that removing

Answer (score 0):

Ia km still getting the same error after Setting constant layout_width and height. I observed that removing

```
>   <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar
>           android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
>           android:layout_margin="20dp"
>           android:layout_width="10dp"
>           android:layout_height="30dp"
>           android:layout_weight="0.10"
>           />
> 
>       <uk.co.daentech.circulardemo.widgets.ProgressBar
>           android:id="@+id/progress_bar2"
>           android:layout_margin="20dp"
>           android:layout_width="10dp"
>           android:layout_height="30dp"
>           android:layout_weight="0.11"
>           />
```

eliminates the error.

I have a seperate Code that designs the Progressbar.